# How can I implement some audio codecs to my Android app?

Tags: android, flutter, audio

I want to build an Android music player that supports DSD, ALAC, RAW and TrueHD audio playback, but I don't know how to implement those to my Android app. The app will be targeted for Android 10 and newer and will be built with Flutter.

I'm new in overall development so basically I'm blind here.